# How to get value from onkeyup?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I get input values that change with user data into javascript function? I couldn't do it with onchange. My example code block is as follows.

Thanks..

- The value must initially be 0.
- Changing values need to be assigned to a variable within the demo () function.

```
<input type="text" name="from" id="from" value="0"/>
<input type="text" name="to" id="to" value="0"/>
```

[jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/0onzLqu3/)

```
function demo() {
    
    var x = document.getElementById("from").getAttribute('value');
    var y = document.getElementById("to").getAttribute('value');

    console.log(x, y);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way you can get the new value inside demo every time it changes:

```js
function demo() {
  const from = document.getElementById("from");
  console.log(from.value);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="from" id="from" value="0" onkeyup="demo()" />
```

Answer (score 0):

That's how, for example, you can do it:

```
function demo() {
    
    var x = document.getElementById("from");
    var y = document.getElementById("to");
        
    x.addEventListener('input', function(evt) {
        console.log('x='  + evt.target.value);
    });
    
    
    y.addEventListener('input', function(evt) {
        console.log('y='  + evt.target.value);
    });

}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6nr2zk9h/